# The term New-AzPortalDashboard is not recognized as a name in a azure pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, ansible, azure-dashboard

In summary I am ask to add an Azure Dashboard via an ansible playbook.
I always get the error "The term New-AzPortalDashboard is not recognized as a name"

There is a pipeline file that

- install python
- "pip install ansible"
- "pip install -r [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/azure/dev/requirements-azure.txt"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible-collections/azure/dev/requirements-azure.txt%22)
- "ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection"

In the playbook it's basically doing stuff with an api and "include_tasks" an yml file.
This yml file call a ps1 file to create stuff.

In that ps1 file I added a function to get the format of a azure dashboard do some update and call the New-AzPortalDashboard.

```
function Add-Dashboard {
param ([String]$subscriptionID,[String]$resourceGroup,[String]$apiManagementName,[String]$dashboardTitle,[String]$location)

$file = New-TemporaryFile

$Content = Get-Content ./templates/api-management-dashboard.json  
$Content = $Content -replace '<subscriptionID>', $subscriptionID
$Content = $Content -replace '<ressourceGroupName>', $resourceGroup
$Content = $Content -replace '<apiManagementName>', $apiManagementName
$Content = $Content -replace '<dashboardTitle>', $dashboardTitle
$Content = $Content -replace '<location>', $location
$Content | Set-Content $file

$DashboardParams = @{
  DashboardPath = $file
  ResourceGroupName = $resourceGroup
  DashboardName = $dashboardTitle
}
New-AzPortalDashboard @DashboardParams

Remove-Item -Path $file
}
```

I try to Install-Module for "Az", "Az.Portal" and "Az.Ressource"  in the pipeline and the ps1 but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the solution here: [Azure DevOps CI/CD missing command: New-AzPortalDashboard](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-cicd-missing-command-new-azportaldash/1542343)

Additionally, verify you are using `pwsh core` on your build agent:

for classic:

[image]

for yaml:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: .....
    pwsh: true
```

Comment: The second part was not there and it look to work now, Thank you